# what is difference between crypto hash and hashtable hashes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, cryptography

What is a crypto hash and what are some algorithms? How it is different from a normal hash in python? How can I determine which to use?

EX:
**Cryptographic hash function**
hello--aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d
helld--44d634fa6b81353bc3ed424879ffd013501ade53

**hash function**
hash("hello") -1267296259
hash("helld") -1267296266

Please help me

Comment: It seems the cryptographic hash was generated with the SHA-1 algorithm, while the normal with the python built-in `hash()`. For cryptographic hashes, read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). However, since the question isn't exactly (and specifically) about algorithms, this is a better fit for [Cryptography SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cryptographic Hash functions are different from Hashtable Hash functions. One main difference is that cryptographic hash functions are designed not to have hash collision weaknesses. They are designed to be more secure and irreversible in most cases. But Hashtable hash functions like [hash](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) are faster and are designed to use to quickly access items in memory or comparing items or etc.

Suppose two differenct Scenarios. If you want to store passwords in a database you must use something like [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) so it is more secure and so slower to generate in order to prevent brute forces. But in another case you just want to have a set of items and check if an item exists in that set. You can simply store a 32-bit or 64-bit hash of items(e.g. classes) and compare hashes quickly instead of classes.

For example for string "hello", it is much faster to compute and store `1267296259` as it is a 32-bit integer and more secure and slower to compute and store `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d`.

P.S. A good example is [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_hash_tables_hashing_dictionary_associated_arrays.php).